# Chrome: no hover state after clicking, happens randomly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Can't believe I didn't find anything about it on google, such an annoying bug, not sure if it even can be fixed without google updating their browser.

Problem description: After clicking on an element which has hover state attached to it, at randomly, the hover state doesn't appear until you **re-click or move the mouse.**

And it gets worse if you try it on a custom checkbox, I guess it's somehow related to the fact that it creates a double click. But still the bug appears even with a **plain div** that has hover attached to it.

All works fine in Firefox and IE.

Video capture with chrome info:

[image]

Test yourself:

```js
i = 0;
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  i++;
  $(".clicks").html(i);
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background: #252B33;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 5px;
  align-items: center;    
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.custom_checkbox {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #5E6569;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked ~ .custom_checkbox {
  background: #FF4F68;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
Number of clicks:
<span class="clicks">
  0
</span>
<br><br>

<div class="button">
</div>

<label class="button">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="custom_checkbox">
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: when I check this with chrome, hover works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing "end task" on google chrome, the problem seems to have disappeared. I did try to close and start the browser before, but only doing the end-task helped.

It must be related to trash collector as I had the browser running and in use daily for a week or so (at nights putting computer to sleep (Windows 8.1)).

Will let you know if it should reappear.